# Isotope is not centering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

I am using ruby on rails, and am having some front-end trouble. I just recently switched form JQuery masonry to isotope. In masonry, my model (called pieces) was centering and animating correctly. Now, with isotope, the animations are working, but it is all happening off to the side, not in the center of the page. How can I fix this?

**Update: Masonry Code**

**This is the code with which centering was working, only using masonry (in pieces.js). I am loading isotope from this rails gem: https://github.com/kristianmandrup/masonry-rails. Site can be viewed at https://www.metallicpalette.com/pieces.**

```
$(function() {
 return $('#pieces').imagesLoaded(function() {
   return $('#pieces').masonry({
     itemSelector: '.box',
     isFitWidth: true
   });
 });
});
```

pieces.js

```
 $(function() {
  $('#pieces').imagesLoaded(function() {
    var $grid = $('#pieces').isotope({
      itemSelector: '.box',
      isFitWidth: true,
       getSortData: {
        title: function(itemElem) { 
          var title = $(itemElem).find('.title').text();
          return title;
        },
        price: function(itemElem) {
          var rawPrice = $(itemElem).find('.price').text();
          var price = parseFloat(rawPrice.replace(/[$\s]/g, ''));
          return price;
        }
      }
    });


    $('.filter-button-group').on( 'click', 'a', function() {
      var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
      $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
    });

    $('.sort-by-button-group').on('click', 'a', function() {
      var sortByValue = $(this).data('sort-by');
      if (sortByValue) {
        var ascending = true;
        if ($(this).data('descending') === true) {
          ascending = false;
        }
        $grid.isotope({ sortBy: sortByValue, sortAscending: ascending });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

index.html.erb (the main page)

```
<div class="button-group center" role="group" aria-label="Filter and Sort">
    <!-- Sort stuff, this all works -->
</div>

<div id="pieces" class="transitions-enabled">
  <% @pieces.each do |piece| %>
    <div class="box panel panel-default <%= piece.genre %>">
       <!-- piece content -->
    </div>
  <% end %> 
</div>
```

pieces.scss

```
#pieces {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.box {
    margin: 5px;
    width: 214px;
}

.box img {
    width: 100%;
}

.panel-default .panel-heading img {
    width: 100%;
}


.isotope,
.isotope .isotope-item {
  /* change duration value to whatever you like */
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
     -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
      -ms-transition-duration: 0.8s;
       -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
          transition-duration: 0.8s;
   }

.isotope {
  -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
     -moz-transition-property: height, width;
      -ms-transition-property: height, width;
       -o-transition-property: height, width;
          transition-property: height, width;
}

.isotope .isotope-item {
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
     -moz-transition-property:    -moz-transform, opacity;
      -ms-transition-property:     -ms-transform, opacity;
       -o-transition-property:      -o-transform, opacity;
          transition-property:         transform, opacity;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The current version of isotope (v3) does not require the .isotope css, FYI. The option *isFitWidth* is now *fitWidth* and used as follows:

```
$('#pieces').imagesLoaded(function() {
var $grid = $('#pieces').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.box',
  masonry: {
 //columnWidth: 100, // You may need to set this value for your specific layout
 fitWidth: true
}
   getSortData: {
    title: function(itemElem) { 
      var title = $(itemElem).find('.title').text();
      return title;
    },
    price: function(itemElem) {
      var rawPrice = $(itemElem).find('.price').text();
      var price = parseFloat(rawPrice.replace(/[$\s]/g, ''));
      return price;
    }
  }
 });
```

Comment: This does not work for me. Do you have another idea? You can see the site live at [this link](https://www.metallicpalette.com/pieces/). Also, I don't I think  I am using version 1 of isotope, because without the css the transitions do not work.

Comment: You are using the first version of isotope. I don't see this code you've included on your page anywhere. At least use v2 to be able to use isfitWidth.

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't see this code on your page anywhere?" Also,  It worked before with masonry - I will update my question to show you how it worked. If it helps, I am loading both isotope and masonry from this rails gem: https://github.com/kristianmandrup/masonry-rails